# How to add multiplication of columns values of the first row to all other rows in a group?

Tags: r, data.table

It might be not difficult, but cannot figure out how to make it in a data.table way. I need a column C3 which is equal to C1*C2 for the first row in a group plus C1*C2 for the current row.

Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)
df = data.table( G = c(rep("G1", 3), rep("G2", 3)),  Index = c(1:3, 1:3), C1 = 1:6, C2 = 4:9)
```

The final table should look like:

```
G   Index   C1  C2  C3
G1      1    1   4  NA
G1      2    2   5  14
G1      3    3   6  22
G2      1    4   7  NA
G2      2    5   8  68
G2      3    6   9  82
```

For simplicity: it doesn't matter what value will be in C3 with Index == 1.

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is

```
df[,  C3 := c(NA, (C1 *C2)[-1]) + first(C1) * first(C2), G]
df
#    G Index C1 C2 C3
#1: G1     1  1  4 NA
#2: G1     2  2  5 14
#3: G1     3  3  6 22
#4: G2     1  4  7 NA
#5: G2     2  5  8 68
#6: G2     3  6  9 82
```

---

Or slightly compact

```
df[, C3 := {v1 <- C1 * C2; c(NA, (v1 + v1[1])[-1])}, G]
```

Comment: @Sergiy  You seem to want the first row as NA, so I removed that and replaced with `NA` by concatenating